# Probability with Contingency table

Tags: probability

On completion of a programming project, four programmers from a team submit a collection
of subroutines to an acceptance group. The following table shows the percentage of subrou-
tines each programmer submitted and the probability that a subroutine submitted by each
programmer will pass the certication test based on historical data.

Programmers
A
B
C
D

Proportion of subroutines submitted
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4

Probability of acceptance
0.55
0.6
0.95
0.75

(a) What is the proportion of subroutines that pass the acceptance test?

(b) After the acceptance tests are completed, one of the subroutines is selected at random and
found to have passed the test. What is the probability that it was written by Programmer
A?

So for part (a) I multiplied 0.55*0.6*0.95*0.7 which was equal to 0.23.
Does that mean the propoertion of subroutines that pass the acceptance test os 2?

(b) I dont have any idea how to go about this part.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The proposed answer to (a) is not correct. With probability $0.1$ the thing came from A, and then probability of pass is $0.55$;  with probability $0.2$ it came from B, and then probability of pass is $0.6$; and so on. So prob of pass is $(0.1)(0.55)+(0.2)(0.6)+\cdots$.